# creating dynamic navigation in zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Currently, I am working on a project using Zend framework 3. In this I have to create dynamic navigation means getting navigation menu(data) from the database. I have already created the static navigation as described in

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/navigation/#setting-up-zend-navigation

but not able created this dynamically.

Comment: You've missed the link from your post.

Comment: i have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the controller read the values from your database and then pass them on to the viewmodel. Something like this:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet; 

function indexAction() {
    $statement = $driver->createStatement('SELECT menu FROM database');
    $statement->prepare();
    $result = $statement->execute($parameters);
    if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
        $resultSet = new ResultSet;
        $resultSet->initialize($result);
    }

    return new ViewModel(array('entries' => $resultSet));
}
```

Then you can get at the entries in your view .phtml

```
<?php foreach($this->entries as $entry) {
        echo $entry . PHP_EOL;
}?>
```